# Where can I ask about POS software or hardware?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is [point of sale](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/point_of_sale#Noun) (POS) software or hardware ever discussed on this site?

Is this an appropriate site for POS questions? I think that it is, but I do not see any strings for this subject.

For example: [Radiant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_Systems), [Aloha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_Systems#Acquisitions), Micros, and Posiflex.

Answer (score 14):

I would say:

Questions about specific POS software/hardware: [Super User](https://www.superuser.com)

Questions about writing your own POS software: [Stack Overflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com)

Questions about security/network architecture for a distributed POS system: [Server Fault](https://www.serverfault.com)

Answer (score 3):

There have been questions (which I've attempted to help answer) on Stack Overflow about point of sale systems. If you think about it, POS systems are essentially embedded systems, and programming for any system is fair game on Stack Overflow.

If you want to get information about the merits of Ingenico's pinpads vs. VeriFone's, then the discussion probably belongs on Super User. If you want to ask questions about the architecture of your back-end servers that feed to your payment processor, Server Fault is probably your best bet.

Really, just ask your question wherever seems best to you. If the community disagrees, it will get moved to the correct site.

Answer (score 1):

Um, [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) (SU) I'm thinking? Others may have less of a conflict suggesting SU, only because it appears to be the default location for anything not programming, meta, and servers.

If you're developing a POS solution, and have programming questions you should ask them on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that Super User would be the most ideal. I just could not make any guarantees that you would get a lot of answers.